# Pairing parameterisation and fixtures in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a python package that checks the formatting of data stored in Excel files. There are various different sheets to check with different formats and in my `pytest` setup I have some example files that are expected to throw different kinds of errors or pass. Because these files are reused across multiple tests, I have them as a fixture in `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', params=['good', 'bad'])
def example_excel_files(request):

    if request.param == 'good':
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(good_file_path, read_only=True)
        return wb
    elif request.param == 'bad':
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(bad_file_path, read_only=True)
        return wb
```

What I want to be able to do is to use this fixture in different tests but specify what the expected values are for a particular test as parameterisation to the test, to keep the information for a test together with the test. For a toy example:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'expected_values',
    [(0, 20), 
     (30, 20)
      ]
)
def test_this_function(example_excel_files, expected_values):

    n_errors, n_rows = expected_values
    output = this_function(example_excel_files['worksheet'])

    assert output.n_errors == n_errors
    assert output.n_rows == n_rows
```

As it stands, that repeats each parameterisation for each fixture param value (good with row 1, good with row 2, bad with row 1, etc). What I want to be able to do is to pair the fixture and parameterisation, so that the first set of examples is checked using `good` and the second set using `bad`. Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [indirect parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization) to add the fixture parameters to the test parameters instead of directly providing them in the fixture. Specifically, you can use indirect parametrization [on particular arguments](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments) here.

For that, you have to remove the parameters from the fixture and add them as indirect parameter to the parametrization, e.g. something like:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')  # params removed
def example_excel_files(request):
    if request.param == 'good':
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(good_file_path, read_only=True)
        return wb
    elif request.param == 'bad':
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(bad_file_path, read_only=True)
        return wb


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'example_excel_files, expected_values',
    [('good', (0, 20)), ('bad', (30, 20))],  # added params
    indirect=['example_excel_files']  # take actual params from fixture
)
def test_this_function(example_excel_files, expected_values):
    n_errors, n_rows = expected_values
    output = this_function(example_excel_files['worksheet'])

    assert output.n_errors == n_errors
    assert output.n_rows == n_rows
```

This way, you directly pair the example files with the respective expected results, and will get only one test per pair.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it had to be using indirect but couldn't get my head around the docs and this use case.

Comment: The pytest documentation has been reworked recently and is much better now IMO -  I added a link to the description of particular arguments.